# Images doesn't go Full Screen when loaded on iframe

Tags: javascript, php

I have a iframe which calls severals url's, some code and KPI's.
Now I am trying to build a presentation like google slides, that shows images and change every 30 seconds. I read the images directly from folder, but I am unable to get it to go fullscreen, It always get the original image properties.

```
<?php

$pasta = 'imagens_comunicados_internos/';
$arquivos = glob("$pasta{*.jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);

$total_imagens = count($arquivos);

foreach ($arquivos as $img) {
    echo 'https://localhost/tv/' . $img . "</br>";
}


$pasta = 'imagens_comunicados_internos/';
$arquivos = glob("$pasta{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);

$i = 0;
$imagens = array();

foreach ($arquivos as $img) {
    $imagens[] = 'https://localhost/tv/' . $img;
    $i++;
}


?>

<script>
    //'https://localhost/tv/index.php',
    //'https://localhost/tv/index.php?acao=1'
    url = [''

    ];

    urls = url.concat(<?php print_r(json_encode($imagens)) ?>);

    position = 0;
    element = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

    element.onload = frameLoaded;

    next();

    function next() {
        if (position >= urls.length) {
            position = 0;
            element.src = urls[position];

        } else {
            element.src = urls[position];
            position += 1;
        }
    }

    function frameLoaded() {
       setTimeout(next, 5000);

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading the image directly in the iframe will show the image at it's regular size. If you want it to be bigger, wider, etc, you will instead need to load an HTML page that loads your image. On that HTML page, use CSS to make it fill the page window.

You could do this with parameters and a PHP page that loads an image passed to it via query string parameter.

If you don't have an HTML page show your image in your iframe, you will not be able to make the image fill the page. It will show it at the exact image size.